# Fit cannot be used with a Target Picasso Android

Tags: android, picasso

I want to use fit() with a target. But it won't let me.
What can i do else? I want to do something like this:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImage).fit().into(target);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using fit() your target must be an ImageView.

From the javadoc:http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fit--

```
public RequestCreator fit()

Attempt to resize the image to fit exactly into the target ImageView's bounds. 
This will result in delayed execution of the request until the ImageView has been
laid out.

Note: This method works only when your target is an ImageView.
```

Comment: My target is an imageview? in onBitmapLoaded im setting the imageview. But i can not use fit yet. how can i use fit?

Comment: @Shahryar the only way to use `fit()` is loading image `into(imageView)`, not `into(Target)`.

Comment: @isma3l You need to change `Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImage).fit().into(target);` to `Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImage).fit().into(imageView);`. Don't forget, if you need it, you can also call `.centerInside()` or `.centerCrop()` straight after `.fit()`.